# How to read from specific Kafka partition in Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have three partitions for my Kafka topic and I was wondering if I could read from just one partition out of three. My consumer is spark structured streaming application.

Below is my existing kafka settings in spark.

```
  val inputDf = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
  .option("subscribe", topic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can read from specific partition.

```
 val inputDf = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
  .option("assign", """{"topic":[0]}""") 
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()
```

PS: To read from multiple partitions instead of 1--> """{"topic":[0,1,2..n]}"""