# Executing Spark Jobs with Shared Kafka Topic Across Multiple Clusters in Structured Streaming API

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working on a Spark project where I need to run jobs on two different clusters, both using the same Kafka topic. I want these jobs to efficiently share the load and balance partitions within the Structured Streaming API. It's crucial to avoid any data duplication during this process. How can I achieve this using Spark's Structured Streaming API?

In my attempts to address this, I experimented with distinct `group.ids` and varied checkpoint locations, but encountered issues with data duplication. Even when using the same group id with different checkpoint locations, duplicates persisted. Additionally, employing the same group id and checkpoint location resulted in an error indicating that concurrent updates to the checkpoint were not allowed.

Comment: How many partitions you have?

Comment: I have 92 partitions

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding the requirement completely.
You have 2 different streaming jobs consuming from same Kafka topic? Writing to 2 different targets or same target?

Anyways I am guessing it is same target , if it is same target then check this out, divide partitions to read between both consumers .i.e. out of 92 partitions read 46 for each consumer —->
[How to read from specific Kafka partition in Spark structured streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703838/how-to-read-from-specific-kafka-partition-in-spark-structured-streaming)

Comment: please read the below, answer Thanks..

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use single consumer?

Comment: Yes, we will be deploying in two different regions, that’s why we need two different consumers working with same group.id, to load balance each other.